# What is best way to find different keys and values in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What is best way to find different keys and values in python dictionary?

### Rules:

1. Check input and contains keys and values are same, if yes return True

   ```
   Contains = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5 }
   input = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5 }
   ```

   Expected Output: `True`
2. Check input and contains values are different , if dirrent return False

   ```
   Contains = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5 }
   input = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 6 }
   ```

   Expected Output: `False` (Reason `e` values are different)
3. Check input and contains Keys are different for same values, if different return `False`

   ```
   Contains = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5 }
   input = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "f": 5 }
   ```

   Expected Output: `False` (Contains key `"e"` is 5 and input key `"f"` is 5)
4. Input contains extra keys and values but does not present in Contains dict hence no duplicates return `True`

   ```
   Contains = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5 }
   input = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}
   ```

   Expected output: `True` (input has extra key value that is `f` and 6 but it does not duplicating )

### Code to achieve:

```
Contains = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6 }
input = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6}

def key_value_check(Contains, input):
    for k, v in input.items():
        if k in Contains.keys():
            if v != Contains[k]:
                return False
        if v in Contains.values():
            try:
                if v != Contains[k]:
                    return False
            except Exception as e:
                return False
    return True
print(key_value_check(Contains, input))
```

Code is working but required best way or one liner code to achieve this.

Comment: What do you consider "best"?

Answer (score 0):

```
def oneliner(a, b):
    return all([a.get(i) == b.get(i) for i in a.keys()])
```

Comment: What you wrote is equivalent to `a == b`. And it doesn't uphold all the requirements.

Comment: which requirements are not met?

Comment: The example in rule #4 is supposed to return true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all( Input.get(c,0)==n for c,n in Contains.items() )
```